# Can't make CAS Single Sign Out work with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

I'm not finding any actual guides as to implement the Single Sign Out CAS feature on my apps. I've tried a number of answers here on SO, but none worked(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891653/single-sign-out-with-spring-security-and-cas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834710/spring-security-and-cas-integration)). Also, there's no examples to be found of the Spring Security+CAS using the Java configuration, so i'm also a bit lost on that. I cannot even figure out if this is the actual URL that i should be using, as the documentation tells me to use "/j_spring_security_logout", and that's just redirecting me to a blank index page, as my index page is working if i access it normally(albeit the console shows all the correct requests, like the JS and CSS). Would really appreciate some guidance, as there's NO documentation that i could find that are using the Java annotation. Thanks in advance!

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String CAS_URL = "https://localhost:8443/cas";
    private static String APP_URL = "https://localhost:8443/i9t-YM";

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService(APP_URL+"/j_spring_cas_security_check");
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas20ServiceTicketValidator());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only");
        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationUserDetailsService authenticationUserDetailsService() {
        return new TestCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public Cas20ServiceTicketValidator cas20ServiceTicketValidator() {
        return new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator(CAS_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return casAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl(CAS_URL+"/login");
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleSignOutFilter SingleSignOutFilter(){
        return new SingleSignOutFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter requestLogoutFilter(){
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler handler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        handler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        handler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter(APP_URL, handler);
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("joe").password("joe").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter());
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        http.addFilterBefore(requestLogoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(SingleSignOutFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                ;
        http.logout()
        .deleteCookies("remove").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("cas/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        //http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403.html");
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

}
```

The SSOut Filter on my Web.xml, dunno exactly why i added it:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
  </filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Why don't you write a controller method, in which you can manually logout the user and redirect the user wherever you want. I would go by making the user authentication as null.

Comment: @WeareBorg But that's the thing: isn't Spring security supposed to do that for me? As far i understood it from the documentation, i just need to make it so that Spring would invalidated the session when i it receives a '/j_spring_security_cas_logout', and then the SSOut would be optional from CAS's point of view. Unless i didn't really understood it. Let me check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my configuration for single sign out over spring security with cas integration:

```
<bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter" />

<bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg
        value="${cas.server.address}/logout?service=${cas.server.address}" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_logout" />
</bean>
```

And you should add these filters to your `springSecurityFilterChain`:

```
<sec:filter-chain pattern="/logout*" 
    filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,singleLogoutFilter,casAuthenticationFilter" />
<sec:filter-chain pattern="/j_spring_cas_security_logout*"
    filters="requestSingleLogoutFilter" />
```

Comment: As I don't deal with this anymore, I'm accepting this answer anyways. However, I have no way of testing it anymore now, sorry. But thanks anyways!

Comment: @Yuri-M-Dias I have experience with cas for multiple years and this is what i did in our project and it works